# Why is the compiler decorating an extern "C" function as a C++ function?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, linker-errors

The linker is giving me the following error:

> Error 27  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003C0) "**extern "C"** int
>   __cdecl **InitDSPs(void)**" **(?InitDSPs@@$$J0YAHXZ)** referenced in function "public: static unsigned int __clrcall
>   HikInterface::HikController::InitializeDSPs(enum
>   HikInterface::VideoStandard)"
>   (?InitializeDSPs@HikController@HikInterface@@$$FSMIW4VideoStandard@2@@Z)

As you can see, the linker seems to be expecting a C++ style decorated function, ignoring the `extern "C"` linkage specification.   **This only happens on a 64-bit build; The 32-bit build compiles perfectly fine.**

I already inspected the exported symbols of the 64-bit .lib file I intend to link and they are not decorated as expected, just like the 32-bit .lib file.  I am also sure the project is linking against the correct .lib file.

Here is how the offending function is declared on the header file

```
#define DLLEXPORT_API  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
...
DLLEXPORT_API int __stdcall InitDSPs();
```

(I already tried switching `dllexport` for `dllimport`, as this project is consuming the DLL, but the error stays the same)

**Any clues or suggestions?**

Comment: It is just a quirk in the linker, specific to C++/CLI code.  The actual signature is fine.  Well, other than the clear mismatch between `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`, you'll have to fix that one.  Finding only a dllexport declaration back cannot be correct of course, there is another one, somewhere.

Comment: You are right @HansPassant, I switched to the 32-bit build and removed the .lib from the linker input to force the error, and it too shows the decorated C++ signature.  If you post your comment as answer, will gladly accept it.

Comment: @HansPasant, turns out the vendor packaged a 32-bit build on their 64-bit SDK   ¬¬    Thanks again!